# App Android Comandos de voz

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo una actividad que reproduce un video nativo con video view, mi duda es, ahi forma de meter comandos de voz en esa pantalla sin necesidad de algún botón, para por ejemplo, pausar el video, darle siguiente.   Revise App Actions pero al parecer, solo son comandos por ejemplo, abrir tal actividad y iniciar tal cosa, pero no se si se puede estando ya en la pantalla.

De antemano Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo esta documentación

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/android-getting-started